# Truffle incompatible with ESMs (ES5 / ES6 modules with "type": "module" in package.json)?

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-contract

is it possible to execute truffle commands inside a folder in "ESM mode", i.e. package.json contains "type": "module", uses import instead of require etc.?

Here is what I get when I run a truffle command inside such a project:

```
$ truffle migrate --network mainnet --reset
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /var/MyESMFolder/truffle/truffle-config.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of /var/MyESMFolder/truffle/truffle-config.js from /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/original-require/index.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename truffle-config.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from /var/MyESMFolder/package.json.

    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:363:5)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:13)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:989:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:19)
    at Object.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
```

I followed the advice stated in the error message `Instead rename truffle-config.js to end in .cjs,` but it only makes the truffle-config file invisible:

```
$ truffle migrate --network mainnet --reset
Could not find suitable configuration file.
Truffle v5.4.1 (core: 5.4.1)
Node v16.3.0
```

So `truffle-config.cjs` is not "seen" by Truffle at all due to the "wrong" extension; apparently it must be called *exactly* `truffle-config.js` and nothing --absolutely nothing!-- else?!

Is there a hidden/undocumented option to specify a different config filename in truffle? Or any other known way to run truffle from inside an ESM folder?

Note: Truffle is installed globally (`npm i -g truffle`)

I can't possibly be the first one to run into this... Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/2354

So *truffle --config truffle-config.cjs compile* works.